# Xml query in LinqToSql

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-sql

I have a XML column in a database and I'd like to query this XML using Linq(toSQL) in an efficient way.

```
MyTable.Select(e => e.XmlObject.Element("Phone").Value)
```

... Seems this queries the db for XmlObject but process Element("Phone") part outside the database? How do I create the query so that native SQL XML functions are used? (Do I want that?)

Updated: Would using a sproc be faster that the alternative used above?

Comment: I don't think Linq2Sql supports native SQL XML functions, but I might be wrong.

Comment: You think you work around it with a sproc though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue with my XML column data - the only solution I had at the time was to get the whole XML column, convert to a string and do a string-search on it. Very kludgy.

However I now have [a solution I have posted on my blog](http://conficient.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/querying-xml-fields-in-linq-to-sql/): write a SQLCLR function on the server, and expose these to LINQ to SQL as a scalar function - these can be called as part of a LINQ query and will execute on the server.

For example:

```
var db = new MyDataContext();
var query = from x in db.MyTable 
            where db.XmlGetElementValue(x.XmlColName, "ElementX") == "somevalue" 
            select x;
```

Where XmlGetElementValue has been added to the dbml.

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ to SQL provider does not support translating C# expressions to a SQL Server XQuery.

You are going to have to use plain old ADO.NET with a string-based query (either to a stored procedure or a parameterized command text query in code) to achieve the results you want.